# HTMLEntities vs. URI.escape for decoding a string in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, html-entities, html-encode

**BACKGROUND:** I am looking to decode strings that include HTML entities - i.e. "c#" should be converted to "c%23".

I have found the [HTMLEntities](http://htmlentities.rubyforge.org/) project to be generally recommended, but have also found what I think is a simpler solution: Using `CGI.escape(*string*)` or `ERB::Util.url_encode(*string*)`.

**QUESTION:** Is there any reason why using CGI.escape or ERB::Util.url_encode for this task is a bad idea? If so, how exactly does one implement HTMLEntities in a Rails 3 project - I can't seem to figure it out from the documentation!

Comment: I think you are confusing HTML entities with Percent Encoding (aka URL Encoding). HTML entities look like this: `&nbsp;` and occur mostly in the html document's text areas. Percent Encoding looks like this: `Hello%20World` and occurs primarily in URLs and links.

Comment: oh, and if you are indeed just working with Percent Encoding, then either of the simpler solutions should be appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about the exact merits of each method. However, if you want to get the htmlentities working you need to add the following to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'htmlentities', :git => "https://github.com/threedaymonk/htmlentities.git"
```

and run:

```
bundle install
```

Then, in your controller:

```
class TestController < ApplicationController

  def index 
    coder = HTMLEntities.new
    string = "<élan>" # or whatever string you want to manipulate
    @test = coder.encode(string) # => "&lt;élan&gt;"
  end 
end
```

and then do whatever you want with the @test variable - write it out on your view page etc.